# Padding impact on li tag background

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I've created menu and I wish to add background into `li:hover` element.
But since I use `padding-right` in my li element and childs I can't add background because the `padding-right` pads the background.

I have also tried replace the elements below

`ul#nav li`,`ul#nav li:first-child`, `ul#nav li:nth-child(5)` (etc)

and add `a` element in the end of each one (So it look like this `ul#nav li:first-child a`) but the result was all `li` elements has been "failling down" (They got lower), I couldn't find a reason for them to get lower.

**Q**: How can I remove `padding-right` participate in element `li` background?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TYVqk/1/) (Full screen mode recommeded)

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to accomplish with the padding.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Khnab/1/. Is it close to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Yes, that what I was looking for, but it doesn't have the same padding like I added and first-child still the same (got padding issue). It will be great if you add answer.

Comment: Why don't you use margin-right? That won't take the background color. And will also keep the things in a place!

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't thought about it.